# Android - is navigation drawer still a standard in new apps?

Tags: android, menu, standards, navigation-drawer

Does a navigation drawer still considered as a standard when developing a new Android app? I see more and more apps without this drawer while Google apps still have it. If not, what is considered as standard for an Android app menu?

Comment: It completely depends on your use case, Showing a single Navigation item in the Nav Drawer is no good design. Similarly showing 6 tabs in a tab layout is no good design. Try referring to Google's Material Design guide to understand this better.

Comment: Ofcourse I'm talking about 3-4-5 items where both can be an option. Lately I saw apps that actually removed the navigation drawer after implementing it, hence my question.

Comment: I would suggest that you go through [this guide](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/index.html). Decide which is most applicable to your use case and develop.

Comment: You can check the beauty of using a Navigation Drawer [Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.havchr.mr2&hl=en)

Comment: Do you really care about?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a menu, then yes Navigation Drawer is still the standard.